# Primefaces FileUpload, After Upload List becomes empty

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

Environment
IDE: RAD 8.5
Server: Websphere 8.5
Primefaces 3.5, JSF 2.0

I have @ManagedBean with @ViewScoped

I want to create a page where multiple attachment will be added and then when user clicks add, all the attachment will be added to database. Method which handles file upload and put the uploaded file in the list is `handleFileUpload`, In this method file successfully uploads because println shows correct file name and other detail.

Method which suppose adds attachment to the database is `addAttachmentAction()`, it prints `List is Empty` so whatever is uploaded is lost.

**EDIT**: The same code works perfectly fine for @SessionScoped bean

Please let me know what is wrong in the code/approach. Complete code is as written below

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class AttachmentBean implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8751473073670649932L;

    private List<AttachedFileBO> attachedFileBOList;
    private List<AttachedFileBO> deletedAttachedFileBOList;
    private AttachedFileBO selectedAttachedFileBO;
    private StreamedContent attachedFileStreamContent;

          //getter setter for above declared field
          .

    public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
        try {
            InputStream tempInputStream;
            tempInputStream = event.getFile().getInputstream();
            attachedFileBO attachedFileBO = new AttachedFileBO();
            byte[] bytes;
            bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(tempInputStream);           
            attachedFileBO.setAttachedFile(bytes);
            attachedFileBO.setAttachedFileContentType(event.getFile().getContentType());
            attachedFileBO.setAttachedFileName(event.getFile().getFileName());
            attachedFileBO.setDbAction("I");
            Random random = new Random();
            attachedFileBO.setAttachedFileTableId(random.nextInt());

            // If file is already attached then add attached file to the list
            if (getAttachedFileBOList() != null && !getAttachedFileBOList().isEmpty()) {
                getAttachedFileBOList().add(attachedFileBO);
            } else {
                List<AttachedFileBO> tempList = new ArrayList<AttachedFileBO>();
                tempList.add(attachedFileBO);
                setAttachedFileBOList(tempList);
            }       
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();            
        }



//After upload when I try to access the list of attachment then method below prints List is Empty
    public void addAttachmentAction() {
        if (getBusinessProcessAttachedFileBOList().isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("List is Empty");
        } else {
            logger.debug("List is NOT Empty");
        }

        //Rest of the coding
        .
        .
    }
}
```

AttachedFileBO

```
public class AttachedFileBO implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 3886993061934034729L;

private int attachedFileTableId;
private int businessProcessId;
private byte[] attachedFile;
private String attachedFileName;
private String attachedFileContentType;
private String attachedFileExtension;
private String dbAction;

//Setter getter
.
.
```

}

Comment: How you invoking `addAttachmentAction` method?And what logic you have in `getAttachedFileBOList`method?

Comment: addAttachmentAction will be invoked when user clicks add getAttachedFileBOList is getter method for private List<AttachedFileBO> attachedFileBOList;</code>

Comment: did you initialize the list? e.g. attachedFileBOList = new List<AttachedFileBO>();